# how to implement a collapsible box in native android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am writing native code for android and wondering how to implement collapsible box like functionality as done in jquery mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html)

In android can I use List item selector to achieve this? Any thought/pointers?

Answer (score 0):

you can expand collapse your textview below link can help you

http://hardiknadiyapara.blogspot.in/2012/09/exapand-collapse-android-textview.html